# Loading SDK Paypal Haw to do it?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, sdk

[I require the access token to make payment tests in Paypal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KukN.png)

[I can't move on this happened I don't know what to do. Sorry I am not a developer. I downloaded the Visual Studio code. in case it's of any use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKwyZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a REST App called "Prueba Pagos".  First, determine whether you want a Live or Sandbox Client ID, and toggle the appropriate mode.

Then click on the App's name to load it.  There will be a Client ID there.

If you don't know what to do with the Client ID, then you need a developer's help.